# Self-study. Does non-convergence in distribution implies non-convergence in probability?

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, convergence

This question arised after reading a solution to the problem.

Given following problem:

[image]

and it's solution:

[image]

I may be wrong but it is not correct solution to a given problem. The fact that $X_n$ doesn't converge in distribution doesn't imply that it doesn't converge in probability. We proved that $X_n$ doesn't converge in distribution but we didn't prove it converge in P. I think there should be more rigorous solution for non-convergence in probability.

Is it a correct solution and non-convergence in D implies non-convergence in P?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems I completely deserve -1 here, because, shame on me, there is absolutely correct solution -- given non-convergence in D we have non-convergence in P.Namely, given non-conv. in D impleis non-conv. in P. Everything is quite straightforward.